# Jumbled Kannada fonts in pdf report using fpdf and php

Tags: php, pdf, fonts

Myself trying to generate pdf files in Kannada font using fpdf and php as,

```
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddFont('Baraha','','baraha.php');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Baraha','',35);
$pdf->Write(10,' cheluva kannaDa nADu');
$pdf->Output();
```

Tried using baraha.ttf, tunga.ttf, lohit.ttf etc but every font gives jumbled output. Below is the output for baraha.ttf font for the above line. How to output correctly in Kannada?

**In Braraha font:** [image: Baraha Kannada font]

**In Lohit Font:** [image: Lohit Kannada Font]

Followed both [this](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm) and [this](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php) tutorials.

**EDIT:** The correct Kannada sentence is **ಚೆಲುವ ಕನ್ನಡ ನಾಡು** for `cheluva kannaDa nADu`. Also please suggest other fonts for correct Kannada sentences. FYI, the same jumbled words are appearing in the case of tcpdf php library and `pdfmake.js` javascript library as well. So can anyone please suggest a best library (either javascript or php) for pdf generation.

Comment: Hello, have you solved the problem? If so then please let me know am also facing the similar issue.

Comment: Latest `pdfmake.js` library works correctly...

Comment: Thank you. Will have a look at it.